# Replicating the iOS time picker in Android

Tags: android, datetimepicker, picker, custom-datetimepicker

I'm trying to write an app that would use the timepicker in Android, but I really would like to implement the one from iOS.

I've had a couple of leads, but haven't struck anything that has worked for me.

My problem is that the time picker is for time but I want to use mine for three different number values that can be chosen (no am/pm) so it seems like [Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) are the way to go, except that they were introduced in API 11.

I've found this [blog](http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html) that seems to give you some code for it, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

I also found [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/checkout), but I don't know how to get the source for it. Can anyone steer me in the right direction for it?

The iOS timepicker looks like this:

[image]

Android wheel looks like this:

[image]

But, I haven't been able to figure out how to get the code for it.

Comment: You might have more luck if you post an image of the thing you are trying to achieve. I am not familiar with iOS time picker so there is nothing really I can suggest.

Comment: Just because android != ios doesn't mean it can't.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in the google code project - https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code from below link for various wheel example:

http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Make sure that you have the svn plugins for download.

Thanks.

Comment: the long is no longer valid