# Implement iOS like time picker in Android

Tags: java, android, ios, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm looking to implement a time picker like below in Android.

I've already looked at http://tolkianaa.blogspot.mx/2012/04/how-to-use-android-wheel-part-ii.html but he has multiple xml files and multiple classes seemingly so I can't see how thats going to work. (Am I missing something?)

I have android-wheel installed so this question is useless [Replicating the iOS time picker in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284200/replicating-the-ios-time-picker-in-android)

The demos from android wheel don't seem to really accommodate it.

Anyway, does anyone have a better way of implementing this is android?

[image]

Comment: this is not an answer but ...why? oh why? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: You should have a look at the stock clock app that comes with Android >= 4.
it implements a time picker very similar to the one you have in your screenshot, but styled for Android.
The usability of this type of time picker is really great. But be cautious to do not copy the look of the iOS picker in Android. The two OS have very different styles and it would just look horribly out of place.
The link provided by @Selvin should be the first step in any Android design process.

Comment: surely android could accept that iOS's way is far better and more practical and just (yet again) copy them

Comment: @Teovald oh I agree the last thing I wanted was a carbon copy. Could you by any chance link me to that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look [at the AOSP source code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse?repo=platform--packages--apps--deskclock#git/src/com%253Fstate%253Dclosed), a clock app is included I think it is the default one that is shipped with ICS & JB (but I have not compiled it to verify).
Also, [the official website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) always have some useful info, you should try to start with this widget. The illustration seems to indicate that it uses buttons instead of swiping, which is strange but even if it is the case it will be a good start to implement a swiping version of this widget.
@Lokesh's link also seems to also fit your needs.